# Configure Autofac IoC for separate projects

Tags: c#, autofac

How should I configure Autofac so my Console Application doesn't have to add a reference to each different implementation of an interface?

I have the following project structure:

App.Core - Class library containing interfaces that will be used on the other class libraries
App.ImplA - Class library implementing interfaces from App.Core
App.ImplB - Class library implementing interfaces from App.Core
App.Console - Console Application referencing App.Core and using Autofac to inject the right reference to the implementation classes

Examples on Autofac website suggest adding the following code to the main project, which in my case is App.Console:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<SomeClass>().As<ISomeInterface>().InstancePerDependency();
var appContainer = builder.Build();
```

But, if I want to decide which implementation class/assembly should be used via config, I won't have a reference to the assembly with the implementation (am I wrong?). Thus I won't be able to reference `SomeClass` on `RegisterType` function.

How can I do this? Is it right?

Comment: I would steer clear of trying to wire dependencies up through config. You lose type safety and it's easier to mess things up (but I'm sure I spelt x right!) - can you not re-think your architecture and avoid doing it this way?

Comment: How it would work if I needed to change from a SQL Server based data layer to an Oracle based data layer? Would I still need to recompile the connected projects? Wouldn't this be the tight coupling that DI/IoC should fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how your app and assemblies are structured, I think you have basically two options.

**If all of the implementations are in the application at the same time** - for example, you have *both* the implementations for a SQL Server data access layer *and* for an Oracle data access layer - then you are stuck with [configuration](http://docs.autofac.org/en/v4.0.0/configuration/xml.html). You may be able to make some of the typing easier by registering multiple related types in [an Autofac module](http://docs.autofac.org/en/v4.0.0/configuration/modules.html) and then using configuration to switch *modules* instead of individual types. For example, all of the SQL Server type registrations would happen in one module and all of the Oracle type registrations would happen in a different module. Configuration would indicate which module to run - a one-line change instead of many lines.

**If you can structure your app to only include implementations you want to use** then you can use [assembly scanning](http://docs.autofac.org/en/v4.0.0/register/scanning.html) to do the registrations. Basically, search for all of the things implementing your interfaces and register them all on the fly. You can also combine this with [Autofac modules](http://docs.autofac.org/en/v4.0.0/configuration/modules.html) by searching for and registering all modules found in application assemblies.

Comment: Currently I have only one implementation (SQL Server), but I already have a requirement to implement another version (Oracle) next year. If I have to add to my main project a reference to the SQL Server implementation, I'd have tight coupling. I have worked previously with Castle Windsor but I don't remember if I had to add this direct reference to one of the implementations during development.

Comment: Assembly scanning shouldn't require a reference. The comment you mentioned doesn't change my answer.